# Can 600W PSU work on 1200VA AVR

Tags: power-supply

This is probably very simple question for everyone on here, but I'm complete newbie when it comes to electronics. Anyway, I'm getting new PC with 600W PSU (my old one had 500W PSU), so I was wondering if 600W PSU would work on 1200VA Automatic Voltage Regulator.

I have this [AVR](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009RA60).

Comment: PC PSUs employ power factor correction, so a 600W PSU should require not much more than 600 VA. So, if all of the specifications are as claimed, it should work.

Comment: You're welcome. That being said, your question does not relate to electronics design, and so is off-topic for this site.

Comment: I see that now, however I assume I need to wait for moderator to move it where it belongs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should post that question in other stack department. Anyway why do you want a "Automatic Voltage Regulator"? would be better to get a Power Supply Unit for your PC. It includes that protections and keep your pc working at power loss situation

Comment: We don't have power outages here where I live, it's very very very rare. Haven't had one in years. However, grid power can be sometimes unstable when it comes to voltage.

Comment: Ok so if you fell you need that equipment is ok, having more VAs is a plus. Note that you can plug multiple things, PC, monitor, laptop, etc, in same Voltage Regulator, so the more stuff you plug more VAs you will need, having a bit more than you require is always good to give a margin

Comment: I use this AVR only for my monitor (around 30W) and my PC (500W old one, new one will be using 600W). I have no intentions to plug anything else in it, I'm fine just to cover monitor + pc case. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: In that case and for the price is a good option and give you a good margin for the future. Also note that you can have a 2000W power supply, but electronics will only use what they need to run, ie: 320W out of 2000W. So your PC even with 600W PSU will draw a bit or lot less than 600W

Comment: Yeah I've figured that out. If I understand correctly - higher system load = more power needed.

Comment: Yes, more load or more hardware. For example two graphic cards will need more power than a single card. Also today PCs have adaptative power, which means they ajust power on the go. If your PC is idle, the CPU clock goes down in order to save power, HDD stop, etc...

Comment: Thanks for indepth answer, much appreciated! Sadly I can't upvote as I don't have needed rep. :(

Comment: no problem, you welcome ;)

Comment: @MerkisL a PC PSU will have an efficiency of about 85% and a power factor of about 0.7 without any power factor correction or under unfavorable load conditions. Hence your calculation should be 600/(0.85×0.7) = 1010 VA as a guideline for the worst-case capacity required to run this. (Power factor is a measure of the phase alignment of the voltage and current waveforms.) 1200 VA is enough, but don't get the idea from Tiago's comments that 600 VA would have been. By the way, PSUs are more efficient close to maximum load, so don't grossly overspecify the PSU capacity. Few PCs require 600W.

Comment: I see, thanks. What'd happen if I had more appliances that need more watts (more than 600W) on that 1200VA AVR?

Comment: @OleksandrR. I never told he need 600VA, i said more VAs is a plus and better give a good margin, in fact that was your comment... "so a 600W PSU should require not much more than 600 VA". But obviously Watts not equal to Volt-ampere and conversion is not direct.

Comment: @Tiago you stated that a PC with a 600W PSU will require less than 600W in actuality. This is not a good premise. I said that it would require, as a minimum, slightly more to provide some margin for safety, on the assumption that nobody is going to choose a 600W PSU when the PC only requires 400W, and that efficiency and power factor have to be considered as well. Your advice is essentially that more is better, which is not exactly quantitative and not a very useful basis for a decision. I thought it better to give OP a way to justify to themselves whether a given capacity is enough, or not.

Comment: @MerkisL in that case you would need to calculate how many VA they each require, by estimating their power consumption, efficiency, and power factor, and add it all up. Again, it is a worst-case estimate, but one should always estimate according to the worst case to avoid trouble.